# missing parameter type for expanded function in List[_]

Tags: scala

Scala Version 2.10.0

I create a function like this.

```
def rm(workingSet: List[_])(item: Any)(f:(List[_], Any) => List[_]) = f(workingSet, item)
```

I get the following error:

```
scala> val data = List(1,2,3)
scala> rm(data)(1)((list, item)=>list filter (_ != item))
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$bang$eq(item))
          rm(data)(1)((list, item)=>list filter (_ != item))
                                                 ^
```

Can somebody explain this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of scala are you using?

Comment: I tested as far back as `2.8.0` and I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: possibly an instance of [SI-5330](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5330)

Answer (score 0):

There are times when the compiler cannot infer the type and you have to help it. Try "list.filter(_ != item)" - using the "." notation often does the trick.  If that doesn't do it, you can always do "list filter { li: Int => li != item }". FWIW, the scala 2.10 REPL doesn't seem to have a problem inferring the parameter type for me.

Comment: type inference has nothing to do if one uses operator notation or not. It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get your example to compile was to introduce a type parameter:

```
def rm[A](workingSet: List[A])(item: A)(f:(List[A], A) => List[A]) = f(workingSet, item)
```

Any particular reason why you are using existentials and `Any`?